# update object within the same query after selecting it

Tags: java, hibernate

so let's say i pull an object through a named select query.  can i do do something like this to update a specific object instead of making another query?

```
 Query result = session.getNamedQuery("findByName").setString("name",nm);
 obj = result.list();
 obj.get(0).setLastName(newLastName);
 result.executeUpdate();
```

Doing the above gives me a "not supported for select queries"

Answer (score 0):

Query result = session.getNamedQuery(..
is creating Query for a select statement and you cannot update on the same query. That's why you are seeing the error.

Thanks,
http://javaho.wordpress.com